# Specify that the lower value of a certain error measure is better in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can one specify that the lower value of a custom "score()" function added to a scikit-learn estimator, is better than a higher value. It says in this link how you can do this for a function that you can explicitly use as input to GridSearchCV by creating a scoring object.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-score-functions

But I want my "score()" function inside the class to be selected automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just negate the function, i.e. return minus the value you want to minimize. This is what the built-in loss-based scorers do (the log-loss-based one in particular).

Comment: Sure. That's obvious. It's what I've been doing all this while.

Comment: @user1953384: it's also the only way to do this (and I'm the guy who pushed that through). There was an API design to put a `greater_is_better` attribute on the scorer, but it was too complicated to maintain. It wouldn't have worked with `score` methods on estimators, either.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! That's what I wanted to know - if it was possible to use something like the greater_is_better attribute with the score function of an estimator.